# Comos Hub - list of all market's and exchange's addresses

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, cosmos, cosmos-sdk

I'm preparing airdrop for my project and want to exclude all exchanges and markets from it. Is there a list of all the exchanges and brands operating on CosmosHub available somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's anything that is perfectly up to date. But you could try using the [CoinGecko API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) to build a list.

Use the `/coins/{id}` api to filter for `cosmos` data.  Then you could try filtering for only DeFi exchanges, or whatever else your requirements are. You'll need to use their other APIs to build the filter.